# How to prioritize VS Code Auto-Import modules from my local directories over node_modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I often face an issue with the auto-import feature in VS Code where, upon typing the name of a module that exists both as a local module (or function) and within `node_modules`, VS Code's auto-import feature prefers the version in `node_modules`.

For example, when I type `cx` and save, the auto-import adds:

```js
import { cx } from "class-variance-authority";
```

However, I would like it to prioritize and auto-import my local version instead, like so:

```js
import { cx } from "@/app/_utils/cx";
```

**Another example**, when I type <Button/> and save, the auto-import adds:

```js
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
```

However, I would like the auto-import to add my local version, like so:

```js
import Button from "@/app/components/Button";
```

If this configuration cannot be achieved directly in VS Code, I would appreciate any recommendations for an extension that could facilitate this.

Comment: Recommending libraries, plugins, software etc. is out of scope for StackOverflow. But you can look at the [VS Code issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) if some change like this is already proposed. Alternatively find a community / forum for software recommendations.